How to put std::function in a smart pointer like std::unique_ptr and use it?
How to put std::function in a smart pointer like std::unique_ptr and use it?
I have already tried but it didn't work.
Here is the code that I tried already:
const inline void PrintSection(TurboINI::types::section &section)
{
    std::cout << "[\"" << section.GetKey() << "\"]\n";

    auto PrintSectionContent =
        std::make_unique<std::function<void(TurboINI::types::section &)>>([&](TurboINI::types::section &_section) {
            if (!section.GetIntegers().empty())
            {
                for (const auto &i : _section.GetIntegers())
                {
                    std::cout << '\t';
                    PrintInteger(i);
                }
            }

            if (!section.GetStrings().empty())
            {
                for (const auto &i : _section.GetStrings())
                {
                    std::cout << '\t';
                    PrintString(i);
                }
            }
        });

    PrintSectionContent(section);
}


std::function is usually passed around by value. Why do you want to manage it via a unique_ptr ?

@wohlstad I want to manage it via std::unique_ptr because of auto memory management.

std::function is designed to be passed around by value (it is cheap to copy), adding lifecycle managment with unique_ptr only complicates things

A std::unique_ptr is usually used to manage data that was otherwise manually newed (and deleteed). But as I mentioned std::function is not used like that typically.

There is no reason to allocate a function pointer / lambda function on the heap, especially when your going to manage the pointer as a scoped pointer. Just allocate the function pointer on the stack.

What does it didn't work mean? Please show a [mre] including the full text of any error messages. I'd guess that PrintSectionContent(section) didn't compile because you need to dereference the pointer: (*PrintSectionContent)(section)

@АлександрАлибеков The storage of objects with automatic storage (i.e. local non-static variables) are already managed automatically. The only reason for wrapping such objects in a std::unique_ptr is if they are very large.

A std::function is a smart object container for a function.  The extra level of indirection that a std::unique_ptr<std::function<void()>> doesn't get you anything extra, other than more bother.

This question looks like complete overengineering. In this code I do not see any reason to use unique_ptr, but also std::function looks pointless and lambda also do not have reason to be used too. Why you are complicating code so much. Is this some kind "cargo cult programming"?

@MarekR I thought the purpose is to store the function for later use. In that case it does make sense to wrap it, but only in a std::function, without the smart pointer of course.

@wohlstad there is nothing in question indicating this is used later in any form outside of PrintSection. It looks like beginner copied some code without understanding.

@MarekR that is true. I just assumed it is something like that because otherwise it is not clear at all why the OP did not implement the logic directly in PrintSection.


How to put std::function in a smart pointer like std::unique_ptr

What you've already done is ok:
auto PrintSectionContent =
    std::make_unique<std::function<void(TurboINI::types::section &)>>(
        [&](TurboINI::types::section &_section) {
            //....       
        });


and use it?

You can dereference the smart pointer and call the stored function in different ways. Here are two examples:
(*PrintSectionContent)(section);          // 1
PrintSectionContent->operator()(section); // 2

The reason for (...) around *PrintSectionContent in the first variant is because of operator precedence. The function call has higher precedence (2) than indirection/dereferencing (3), which makes *PrintSectionContent(section) the same as ...
*(PrintSectionContent(section));

... which tries to call the unique_ptr (not what it's pointing at) and then dereference the result of that call. You want to dereference the pointer to get a reference to the stored function and then call that.
PrintSectionContent(section); that you have in the question has the same initial mistake but without trying to dereference the value returned by calling the unique_ptr.

I see no reason to use std::unique_ptr (or any smart pointer) here.
A std::function is a relatively lightweight object, and is typically stored or passed around by value.
If you want to keep the callable for later use, you can simply make PrintSectionContent a std::function:
std::function<void(TurboINI::types::section &)> PrintSectionContent =
        [&](TurboINI::types::section &_section) {
        // ...
        };

Then invoke the stored lambda like you attempted:
PrintSectionContent(section);

You can also store the std::function in a member etc., but keep in mind that since it conatins a lambda that captures by reference, when you invoke it the objects it keeps a reference to must be alive.
Note:
If you don't need to store the function for a later use you can simply implement the logic in PrintSection directly - see @MarekR's answer.

Although there's no need for pointer in this particular example, I suppose a valid use-case would be where the function has mutable state.

@TobySpeight Not sure I understand your meaning. Even if it has mutable state, why wouldn't using a std::function directly (without a smart pointer) good enough ?

Shared ownership - call a single instance from several places (and where we can't simply use a reference because we have nothing guaranteed to outlive the call sites).  But that's a very rare case, that I've never ever needed and don't expect to, and it's not what's happening here.  Just trying to invent a case where it might conceivably be useful.

@TobySpeight now I see what you mean - that's a valid point. But these are rare cases indeed.

Just make simple function. This code do not contain anything which could rationalize use of std::unique_ptr or std::function or lambda.
const inline void PrintSection(TurboINI::types::section &section)
{
    std::cout << "[\"" << section.GetKey() << "\"]\n";

    if (!section.GetIntegers().empty())
    {
        for (const auto &i : section.GetIntegers())
        {
            std::cout << '\t';
            PrintInteger(i);
        }
    }

    if (!section.GetStrings().empty())
    {
        for (const auto &i : section.GetStrings())
        {
            std::cout << '\t';
            PrintString(i);
        }
    }
}

This does exact same thing as your attempt, but without using extra C++ features.
From my point of view (with current content of question) you've massively overengineered this code.
